# Euro sign issue when reading an RTF file with Python

Tags: python, unicode, rtf

I need to generate a document in RTF using Python and pyRTF, everything is ok: I have no problem with accented letters, it accepts even the euro sign without errors, but instead of `€`, I get this sign: `¤`.
I encode the strings in this way:

```
x.encode("iso-8859-15")
```

I googled a lot, but I was not able to solve this issue, what do I have to do to get the euro sign?

Comment: Don't change the title; rather, mark the correct answer (look for the V mark under the answer score to the left).

Answer (score 5):

The RTF standard uses UTF-16, but shaped to fit the RTF command sequence format. Documented at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding. pyRTF doesn't do any encoding for you, unfortunately; handling this has been on the project's TODO but obviously they never got to that before abandoning the library.

This is based on code I used in a project recently. I've now released this as [`rtfunicode` on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rtfunicode), with support for Python 2 and 3; the python 2 version:

```
import codecs
import re

_charescape = re.compile(u'([\x00-\x1f\\\\{}\x80-\uffff])')
def _replace(match):
    codepoint = ord(match.group(1))
    # Convert codepoint into a signed integer, insert into escape sequence
    return '\\u%s?' % (codepoint if codepoint < 32768 else codepoint - 65536)    


def rtfunicode_encode(text, errors):
    # Encode to RTF \uDDDDD? signed 16 integers and replacement char
    return _charescape.sub(_replace, escaped).encode('ascii')


class Codec(codecs.Codec):
    def encode(self, input, errors='strict'):
        return rtfunicode_encode(input, errors), len(input)


class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    def encode(self, input, final=False):
        return rtfunicode_encode(input, self.errors)


class StreamWriter(Codec, codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass


def rtfunicode(name):
    if name == 'rtfunicode':
        return codecs.CodecInfo(
            name='rtfunicode',
            encode=Codec().encode,
            decode=Codec().decode,
            incrementalencoder=IncrementalEncoder,
            streamwriter=StreamWriter,
        )

codecs.register(rtfunicode)
```

Instead of encoding to "iso-8859-15" you can then encode to 'rtfunicode' instead:

```
>>> u'\u20AC'.encode('rtfunicode') # EURO currency symbol
'\\u8364?'
```

Encode any text you insert into your RTF document this way.

Note that it only supports UCS-2 unicode (`\uxxxx`, 2 bytes), not UCS-4 (`\Uxxxxxxxx`, 4 bytes); `rtfunicode` 1.1 supports these by simply encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair to two `\uDDDDD?` signed integers.

Comment: hey I'm highjacking this because I need some help that you might have: I use your code (or rather the stuff from [here](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2012/06/06/rtf-and-unicode/) (I think that's from you anyway...)). I generated some RTF file with it but when I open it the characters are off anyways. Could it be that I need to write something regarding unicode in the header as well? And no, I did not RTFM. Maybe I should?

Comment: @fabian789: yes, that's me. I released the [code on PyPI as a package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rtfunicode); I've not heard of any problems before now. Are you certain your input is correct?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay I guess that's it. `u"ü".encode('rtfunicode')` works with my header. Don't know what it is that makes my input incorrect, but I'll figure it out, thanks!

Comment: The rtf spec (1.9.1) mentions surrogate pairs explicitly: *"Surrogate pairs like `\u-10187?\u-9138?` must appear inside math object
groups as in this example, or inside a math text-run group `{\mr...}` if not inside a math object."* Though LibreOffice understands the surrogate pairs without a math object too.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: yay for updated specs! I'll see about updating `rtfunicode` then. I see that 1.9.1 was officially published in 2008 but I sure as hell didn't find it in 2012 when I wrote this answer!

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that you're not doing anything wrong. The bad news is that the RTF is being read as ISO 8859-1 regardless.

```
>>> print u'€'.encode('iso-8859-15').decode('iso-8859-1')
¤
```

You'll need to use a [Unicode escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Character_encoding) if you want it to be read properly.

```
>>> print hex(ord(u'€'))
0x20ac
```

Comment: RTF doesn't actually use a standard encoding; Microsoft invented a *new* encoding to support non-ASCII characters instead.